# ScriptJob with return variables function maya Python

Tags: python, scripting, maya, mel

I'm running into a problem with the scriptJob command of maya: if I make a scriptJob to a function without arguments everything works fine, but if I need to pass a variable into that function that will be execute by the scriptJob It returns this error:

```
#Error: TypeError: file <maya console> line 5: Invalid arguments for flag 'ac'.  Expected ( string, string or function ), got [ str, NoneType ]#
```

The code is really simple I want just to understand why this is happening.

```
import maya.cmds as cmds

def a():
    cube = "pCube1"
    cmds.scriptJob(ac = ["pCube2.translateY", delete(cube)])
    return cube

def delete(cube):
    cmds.delete(cube)

cube = a()
a()
```

Hope you can help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's 3 ways you can pass a parameter to your callback function.

## 1:

You can use `partial`. This is often used in custom interface events like `Qt` as well to pass parameters, and you can do the same concept here:

```
from functools import partial
import maya.cmds as cmds


def delete_cube(cube):
    if cmds.objExists(cube):
        cmds.delete(cube)


cube = "pCube1"
cid = cmds.scriptJob(ac=["pCube2.translateY", partial(delete_cube, cube)])
```

## 2:

Similar to the 1st method, another popular way is to use `lambda`. The only advantage is that it's a built-in command and don't need to import any module, but its syntax may be less readable at a glance:

```
import maya.cmds as cmds


def delete_cube(cube):
    if cmds.objExists(cube):
        cmds.delete(cube)


cube = "pCube1"
cid = cmds.scriptJob(ac=["pCube2.translateY", lambda x=cube: delete_cube(x)])
```

## 3:

Or you can pass it as a string, but you need to format your parameters properly including its quotes if the parameter itself is a string:

```
import maya.cmds as cmds


def delete_cube(cube):
    if cmds.objExists(cube):
        cmds.delete(cube)


cube = "pCube1"
cid = cmds.scriptJob(ac=["pCube2.translateY", "delete_cube('{}')".format(cube)])
```

You don't necessarily have to use `.format`, you can concat the strings with `+` or `%`. Personally I prefer the 1st method with `partial` as it feels cleaner with less fuss.

A few closing notes:

- In your callback function you should include a conditional check with `cmds.objExists` to make sure what you're about to delete actually exists, otherwise it will throw an error.
- Don't forget to capture the result of `cmds.scriptJob` in a variable so that you can easily delete it later with `cmds.scriptJob(kill=cid)`.